# Calling a Method of a Subclass From an Array of the Superclass

Tags: java, arrays, class, casting, hierarchy

Consider the following.
You have a Dog Class and a Cat Class, that both extend the Class Animal.
If you create an array of Animals Eg.

```
Animal[] animals = new Animal[5];
```

In this array **5** random Cats and Dogs are set to each element.
If the Dog Class contains the method `bark()` and the Cat Class does not, how would this method be called in terms of the array? Eg.

```
animals[3].bark();
```

Iv'e tried to cast the element, I was examining to a Dog but to no avail Eg.

```
(Dog(animals[3])).bark();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Use `instanceof` (not recommended):

```
if (animals[3] instanceof Dog) {
    ((Dog)animals[3]).bark();
}
```

Option 2: Enhance `Animal` with abstract method:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    // other stuff here
    public abstract void makeSound();
}
public class Dog extends Animal {
    // other stuff here
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        bark();
    }
    private void bark() {
        // bark here
    }
}
public class Cat extends Animal {
    // other stuff here
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        meow();
    }
    private void meow() {
        // meow here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, turns out that my way of casting was incorrect `(Dog(animals[3])).bark();` to `((Dog)animals[3]).bark();`